# java file.exists doesn't find my file

Tags: java, file, exists

I'm using Windows7. I've written this simple java code:

```
package filetest;
import java.io.File;

public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myfile = new File("C://test//test.txt");

        if (myfile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file exists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("file doesn't exist");
        }

    }

}
```

The file DOES exists in C:/test/test.txt, but the answer is that file doesn't exists.
Why?

EDITED:
I've changed the code and it still doesn't find the file, but now it creates the file. So I can write to that directory. And the created file is named "test"

```
package filetest;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myfile = new File("C:\\test\\test.txt");
        final Formatter newfile;
        if (myfile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file exists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("file doesn't exist");
            try {
                newfile = new Formatter("C://test//test.txt");
                System.out.println("file has been created");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);                
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `//` is not a valid directory separator on windows. ``\\`` would work, since that'd just be a regular escaped backslash.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried C:\\test\\test.txt It doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have enough permissions to access this file? Does the user that is running your application have permissions?

Comment: I'm working with an administrator account. I should have permission to access this file, shouldn't I?

Comment: I guess you should. Anyway, if it wasn't the case I believe a SecurityException would be thrown.

Comment: Yes, you should have. Please, open this file properties, click on Security tab and review the file name.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange. The name of the file in the Security tab is: C:\test\test.txt.txt ¿?  And the name of the file created with Formatter (the second code I've written) is C:\test\test.txt. I can't understand what's happening.

Comment: You got it! Change your folder properties, show the extensions and rename your file removing ".txt" from it.

Comment: I dont' think I need to change the folder properties. I already have access to it. And even if I do it, I don't want to change extension to test.txt by hand. I want it to be automatically created with my code and detected with exists. What can I do?

Comment: Anyway, I've done it. It doesn't work :(((((

Comment: Have you read my post above? I've created it with newFile(<path>/test.txt)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to double your slashes. You have to user wether `"/"` or `"\\"`.

**EDIT :**

The weird thing is that I tried it out and both `"/"` and `"\\"` work fine for me. In fact, it works regardless of the number of "/" I use... for example `"C:////test/////////test.txt"` is okay. You have another problem, and I have no idea of what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

In windows path separator used is '\' for these you need to escape backslash.So your code will be something like:

```
public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myfile = new File("C:\\test\\test.txt");

        if (myfile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("file exists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("file doesn't exist");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using *isFile()* instead of exists(). Its a better way of checking if the path points to a file rather than if a file exists or not.  *exists()*  may return true if your path points to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

@SSorensen In your EDITED code, you added the backslash properly

@ line 7

```
File myfile = new File("C:\\test\\test.txt");
```

but you forgot to update slashes with backslashes @ line 14

```
newfile = new Formatter("C://test//test.txt");
```